# Webpack is generating a bundle file for every single SVG file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have a small little react library with a single component, which imports SVGs from an `icons` directory. I'm trying to bundle my project and get one (1) bundle.js file as the output with webpack, but instead I'm getting a bundle.js and a bundle.js.map file for every single SVG file I have in my `icons` directory.

Here's my webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var libraryName = 'bundle';
var outputFile = libraryName + '.js';

var config = {
  entry: __dirname + '/src/index.js',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: outputFile,
    library: libraryName,
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    umdNamedDefine: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        loader: 'svg-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
};

module.exports = config;
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: How are you importing the svg files from your index.js? If you are using `import('filename')`, that will instruct webpack to split that file into a separate bundle. Make sure you are importing the svgs using `require()` or es6 import statements

Comment: Oh ok, that could be the issue, I'm importing it with `import('./path/to/file.svg')`. So is there no way to get it to bundle them as a single output file then?

Answer (score 0):

Use `LimitChunkCountPlugin` and set `maxChunks: 1`:

```js
const webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.LimitChunkCountPlugin({
      maxChunks: 1,
    }),
  ],
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Webpack [svg-inline-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/svg-inline-loader/) instead of svg-loader

```
rules: [
  ...
  {
    test: /\.svg$/,
    loader: 'svg-inline-loader'
  }
]
```

this loader will load svg as inline modules in final bundle file

Comment: I get the same result with svg-inline-loader.